# Is it possible to use mathematical sets and their operations in arduino?

Tags: library, mathematics

In python there is the object set that resembles a mathematical set, namely, you can remove elements from it, add elements to it, you can calculate the intersection/union between two sets, etc.

Is there a library or built-in functions that have those capabilities? I have been unlucky because when I use the word "set" as query term for the engine search, it always sends me to something related to the verb to set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Standard Template Library (STL) can be installed on the Arduino. It is not there by default. That includes things like sets.

One implementation is [here](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/arduinostl/).